# Display Empty Columns Pivot Table with OLAP Data (Filtered)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, olap

I am trying to check values of rows across all columns. My code filters and loop on each category. These data are copied on a certain format to another sheet and will be used as vlookup data. However, there are instances when I change a filter those row data don't have column data. Thus, The column header with no data does not show up in the pivot.  I want these columns to show even if filtered. In normal Pivot table, there is "show items with no data" which will do these function. But in OLAP pivot, this option is greyed out. Tried below code but still did not work.

Are there any ways to do this? Appreciate your help on this. Thanks!

```
Sub DisplayEmptyMembers()
  Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
  Set pvtTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("WeeklySTCperFF")
  pvtTable.DisplayEmptyColumn = True
  pvtTable.DisplayEmptyRow = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pivottable-options-27c02eb7-27de-4b3f-9677-c48e3fe7637b) you'll find something ("Show items with no data on rows -> Note: This setting is only available for an OLAP data source.")

Comment: I am doing a loop with different filters. Thus, there are instances that a certain category is empty. But I am using a standard copy cell reference. Thus, when a category is empty, it will change the data extracted. The setting you mentioned does not really help on the required filtering. Thanks!